# Master page, tab and a postback

Tags: .net, asp.net, telerik, asp.net-4.0

I have a Telerik Tab strip control on a master page as follows.

```
<telerik:RadTabStrip ID="rtsOrders" runat="server" Width="350px" Skin="Outlook" Align="Justify">
   <Tabs>
       <telerik:RadTab Text="Manage Groups" Width="100" Visible="false" NavigateUrl="~/Group/GroupMembers.aspx" />
       <telerik:RadTab Text="Manage Orders" Width="100" Visible="false" NavigateUrl="~/Manager/ManageOrders.aspx" />
       <telerik:RadTab Text="My Orders" Width="100" NavigateUrl="~/Order/MyOrders.aspx" />
   </Tabs>
</telerik:RadTabStrip>
```

All above tab navigation URLs are  content pages. When I click on the tab, I do see flicker and complete page loading even though I did not set Autopostback to true for Radtabstrip.

I put a breakpoint on page load of master page. It does come there on every tab click and when I check for `?page.Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET")`

It comes as nothing.

I really don’t know why page behaves like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When set as a navigation URL, page.Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET") would never come back with the tab in this value; __EVENTTARGET traps the control posting back when the posted source is the same page.   This is not a post but a redirect.

HTH.

Comment: I am Supposed to see complete reload of page? that is what happening now?